# I need a program that will record/log all of the IP addresses I have as they change

Tags: network-monitor

I have dynamically allocated IP addresses which changes every time my router powers off or disconnects for any reason (I have a somewhat reliable ISP so this could be multiple times a day).

I need to keep track of communications I send out and which IP they come from so I can track and note duplicates.

The ideal software would be able to make a new entry in an excel file every time my IP changes.

An absolutely ideal feature would notify me automatically whenever I was switched to an IP which already existed in the log (however unlikely this may be), so I could make the appropriate notes/take the appropriate measures.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want to log the computer’s own IP number used to identify itself on the network? I don't understand what you mean exactly by "I have dynamically allocated IP addresses".

Comment: Yes. The IP addresses that represent my location on the internet are dynamically assigned to me by my ISP.